# Nativescript - Login Page CSS isn't working

Tags: javascript, css, nativescript

I am trying to create a login page. I used the login page template via SideKick and named it login. It created a login folder with login-page.js, login-page.xml, and login-view-model.js. I created a login-page.css file within the same folder as the other ones.

I created a simple style in the css file to make the font color blue for the test class. I applied that to a label in the class field. It will not work. Am I missing anything?

```
<ScrollView>
<StackLayout class="form">
    <Label class="h1 text-center test" text="Login"></Label>
    <TextField class="m-t-10 m-b-10 m-l-15 m-r-15" hint="Email" keyboardType="email" autocorrect="false" autocapitalization="none"
        text="{{ email }}"></TextField>
    <TextField class="m-t-10 m-b-10 m-l-15 m-r-15" hint="Password" secure="true" autocorrect="false" autocapitalization="none"
        text="{{ password }}"></TextField>
    <Button class="btn btn-primary" text="SIGN IN" tap="onSigninButtonTap"></Button>
    <Label class="m-t-10 m-b-10 m-l-15 m-r-15" text="Forgot password?" tap="onForgotPasswordTap"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

```
.test{color: red}
```

[image: CSS Picture]

[image: XML Picture]

Comment: Hi, Welcome, Please post your `code` as a code and not as a screenshot

Comment: @aliusman I can't it cut out the first half of the code. That's why I did the screenshots.

Comment: Hi, Please look at the formatting examples here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code - Posting code helps users to get the right answers, where posting screenshot of your code is not really helpful

Comment: @aliusman I have tried those ways and it skips 2 lines in the code. I tried to space them, put them all in one line, tried adding <br/> tags to them. Nothing I do shows those lines.

Comment: @aliusman Does Codepen work? https://codepen.io/IAmOptimus24/pen/roNrYB

Comment: Please edit your post and put the code in there, you should be able to do that by clicking `{  <CODE>  }`  code tags

Comment: Have you added css in page.js as page.addCssFile(cssFileName);

Comment: @NarendraMongiya I have not. Let me try that.

Comment: @NarendraMongiya I added it, but it didn't work. I put my code in the playground without your edit and it works in the playground, but not on my actual device.

Comment: can you share playground link ?

Comment: @aliusman I have pasted what code I could.

Comment: @NarendraMongiya https://play.nativescript.org/?template=groceries-js&id=OzC8wB

Comment: It is working for me on actual ios device. Which platform are you testing?

Comment: @NarendraMongiya I am using IOS. It works on my device using the playground, but when I use my phone through sidekick it doesn't work. Could there be an issue there?

Comment: @NarendraMongiya found a workaround. The css page wasn't working so I put it in the app.ios.scss file and it worked.